# SharePoint online storage quota not receiving emails

Tags: sharepoint-online, sharepoint-designer

[image]

I am not able to receive the email after exceeding the quota limit. I attached a screenshot for the configuration. I can see red on the percentage column and warning message on the top as well. Can you please suggest to me If I am missing any settings?

[image]

How to customize the exceeding storage email in the SharePoint online?.

Comment: Just to verify, but are you an owner of the site collection?

Comment: yes.. I am the owner of the site collection... Does Microsoft have any batch job running to send the emails about the storage limits?

Comment: its receiving every Saturday.. I do not about functionality of Microsoft batch job behavior. anyone experiencing quota email on Saturday?